# How to create new user on admin page in JHipster?

Tags: jhipster

Let's assume only admin can create new user.

On Administration > User management there is a button ‘Create new user’ but for now it’s useless. Admin can’t set password and activate new user.

The only way I found is:

- logout
- Register a new account on home page
- login again as admin and activate new user

Is there any simple way to create fully working user by admin?

Answer (score 2):

Jhipster uses an invitation email that is sent to the user, if you create a new user as an admin. The user clicks on a link to finish the registration (which is the finish-method after a user resets its account).

We also have some applications where we don't want such an interaction (or even mails, because some users don't have an address...). So we have to change that in the webapp and in spring (rest endpoint and the user service), so that the admin can provide a password.

Answer (score 2):

It requires changes in UserService.java and /src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-dialog.html.
Here are details:
https://codefitter2.blogspot.com/2017/05/how-to-create-new-user-by-admin-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility if you do not have any mailserver, is to:
1. register a user yourself with a test mail adress
2. login as admin
3. activate the user via admin panel

not the best one, but for testing purposes it should be enough